# CGContextSetLineCap/CGContextSetLineJoin ignored when creating ImageContext

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, uigraphicscontext

For some reason, when trying to create a line with round corners, all the others properties are applied beside this two

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
            CGContextSetLineCap(context, CGLineCap.Round) //Ignored
            CGContextSetLineJoin(context, CGLineJoin.Round) //Ignored
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth)
        CGContextSaveGState(context)

        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, bounds.midX, 0)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, bounds.midX, bounds.maxY)
        CGContextRestoreGState(context)
        CGContextStrokePath(context)

         // Drawing complete, retrieve the finished image and cleanup
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Result:

[image]

**Any suggestions?** Thanks!

Comment: As it seems, your line extends over the full range of y-coordinates (0 .. bounds.maxY), so any line caps would be *outside* of the bounds.

Comment: @MartinR , Yap. Thanks. Can you please post an answer so i'll accept it?

Comment: @RoiMulia perfect, thank you. Note that I already removed the ignore tag before commenting.

Comment: @JanGreve Thank you for notify me. Will pay more attention to my tags in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line caps are added *beyond* the endpoints of a path. Your path extends
over the full range of y-coordinates of the bounds, therefore the
line caps are outside of the bounds.